# Getting Source Not Available Error...how do I track down the issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

First I receive an object reference error on my @ViewBag.Title line. When I remove the @ViewBag.Title line from my code I start getting this "Source Not Available" message in Visual Studio.  Does anyone have any ideas on why this would be happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the Screen shot. that may be explain more.

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots Vijay.

Comment: Can you post the view code? Is this happening with every view or just this particular view?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  One of my constructors wasn't instantiating one of my objects before it was trying to be used.  It was weird that the error was pointing to the my ViewBag.Title.